# In Typescript what is array as function name?

Tags: typescript

The below code is correctly compiled and executed by ts-node.

```
class C {
    ["abc"]() {
        return "C";
    }
}

let c = new C();

let className = c["abc"]();
console.log(className);
```

But I don't understand the following as class property.

```
["abc"]() {}
```

I think it involves a concept of computed property, but I don't understand this syntax.

**Question 1:**

["abc"] is an array with one string element at index 0. If you add a function definition around it, then ["abc"](){}, then what is it then? How could you use an array as function name?

**Question 2:**

why not the following way to invoke the member method?

```
c.["abc"]();
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: @SLaks thanks! This is the concept that I didn't know before. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `foo['bar']` and `foo.bar` are equivalent ways to access an object member, you can use the indexer syntax with `['bar']` within [object initializers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and class definitions.

For your example, where the property is statically known at compile-time, this does not really offer you any advantage, since it’s directly equivalent to the following:

```
class C {
    abc() {
        return "C";
    }
}
```

However, the indexer syntax does allow you a few things that otherwise wouldn’t be possible.

For example, you can use member names that are not valid identifiers, e.g. names that start with a number, or have a dash inside:

```
class C {
    ['123foo']() { … }
    ['foo-bar']() { … }
}
```

It also allows you to dynamically specify the member name, by taking it from a variable:

```
let memberName = 'foo';
class C {
    [memberName]() { return 'bar'; }
}
console.log(new C().foo()); // bar
```

This is also used for [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) in JavaScript, which offer a way to define members on objects that are not freely visible but only accessible with a direct access to that same symbol object. This will ultimately allow new high-level functionality, like [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) does for iterating custom types.

Answer (score 0):

> why not the following way to invoke the member method

Yup that would be recommended. But if you want to *power* something by configuration (not static) e.g. a string from the server you can use the indexer syntax.